# How can I fix cloudformation update when resource was changed manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My cloudformation stack has a secret resource deployed to secret manager. But this secret was removed and recreate with the same name manually which happened outside cf stack update.

Now when I update this stack, I got an error: `Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret`. The reason is that even the secret was recreated with the same name, the arn of this secret was changed which makes the logic ID in stack is different.

I have tried to drift the stack but the secret is not showing in the result.

So in this case, how can I make the stack in sync with existing resources?

Comment: this is called as drift. Are you able to see the drift details from console?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/remediate-drift-via-resource-import-with-aws-cloudformation/

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't detect this change.

Comment: If regular ways don't work, you have no choice as to delete the stack and recreate.

Comment: You first would need to remove it from your existing template and rerun, then you could try the "Import resources into Stack" feature

Comment: but cf doesn't support importing secrets to existing stack

Answer (score 0):

Can you redeploy just the secret resource from your code?
If yes, remove the manually created secret resource from the console, remove secret resource from code, deploy code.
Add resource to code, deploy code again.